# How do you join/union the results of Select queries within a While loop in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, while-loop, union

Here is what I have so far. It's rudimentary and probably a backwards way to do this.

The basic objective is to see which dates are most popular for customers using the service, which lasts as long as they buy it for (serviceduration). Keep in mind I am referring to the dates that the service is bought *for* -- the first day of which is the column `servicedate` -- rather than the date the service was purchased.

This `@d` is my variable date, and I check how many transactions include that date in the range of their service duration. Right now, this outputs a bunch of different select tables. I'd really like it to just add a row to the output of the previous iteration in the While loop to make one table with 2 columns and a row per date.

See below:

```
Declare @d date = '2015-11-01'

While @d < '2016-3-31'
Begin
   Select 
      date = @d, 
      SUM(qty * CASE WHEN @d between servicedate and   dateadd(day, serviceduration, servicedate) THEN 1 END)
   From RI
   Where confdate > '2015-08-31' 

   Set @d = dateadd(day, 1, @d)
End
```

EDIT: I think this did it -->

```
Create Table #TblD(Dt date, Num int)
Declare @d date = '2015-11-01'
While @d < '2016-3-31'
Begin
   Insert into #TblD(Dt,Num)
   Values(@d, (Select SUM( qty * CASE WHEN @d between servicedate and dateadd(day,serviceduration,servicedate) THEN 1 END) from RI where confdate>'2015-08-31'))
Set @d=dateadd(day,1,@d)
End
Select * from #TblD
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using a loop? It would be far simpler and efficient to use a group by here.

Comment: I would need some sample data and expected results. I don't understand the structure enough, nor the problem, to re-engineer the SQL here.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to make a row for each date between '2015-11-01' and '2016-3-31' otherwise.  Not all dates are covered by the servicedate field (though they are most likely all covered by the union of ranges from servicedate through servicedate+serviceduration).

The code above outputs a 1x2 results for each iteration of the loop.
So the first 3 results are:

    "2015-11-01, 28",

    "2015-11-02, 30", and

    "2015-11-03, 31"

But they're separated; I want them to be rows in the same table.

Comment: if you had a "Numbers" table you could generate a row for each date.  Do a google search for `sql server numbers table dates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use a tally table. Not quite sure on the logic of the aggregation you are doing but this is pretty close. In my system I actually have a view named cteTally but for here I split it out. Here is an excellent article about tally tables and how you can utilize them to replace loops. The tally table has been called the "Swiss Army knife of t-sql" by some. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
declare @StartDate date = '2015-11-01'
    , @EndDate date = '2016-03-31';


WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    ),
    MyDates as
    (
        select DATEADD(day, N - 1, @StartDate) as CurrentDate
        from cteTally
        where N <= DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
    )

select md.CurrentDate
    , SUM(qty)
from MyDates md
left join RI on RI.servicedate = md.CurrentDate
    and md.CurrentDate <= DATEADD(DAY, serviceduration, servicedate)
group by md.CurrentDate
```

Comment: I'm haven't looked into tally tables yet.  I'll see what that can lead to.  But I think your code is missing a part.  Servicedate is the field that tells what day the service *begins* - I should have clarified that.  That service can last multiple days (serviceduration). For example, if a service is bought for Monday through Friday, I'd like it to tally each day M, T, W, Th, *and* Friday.

Comment: No problem. Just add a second condition to the join and it will accommodate that. I edited my answer above to include this.

Comment: So I think my edit to the question answered my own question. Is there a reason I shouldn't be using this kind of logic?

Comment: Yes because loops are horribly inefficient. If you like your queries to be super slow then using loops is fine. But if you want them fast you have to start thinking in set and writing set based queries. I provided you an example that should produce the same thing but in a fraction of the time.

Comment: Ok, so I should definitely learn this method.  Can you explain it a little more? I'm not sure if it's working properly. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I get all the wtih/as expressions. Iteratively creating a table with dates from my start date to end date.  But the select statement under it does not solve the problem. Here's an example: say I have 4 orders. One is from Monday thru Thursday. One is Tuesday thru Wednesday. One is Wednesday thru Thursday. And the last is Saturday thru Sunday. (Each of these orders would be a row in RI).  The output should be a tally of 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, 3 for Wednesday, 2 for Thursday, 0 for Friday, 1 for Saturday, and 1 for Sunday.

Comment: NVM, I got it - just had to take the ri.servicedate=md.currentdate from the join and make it a between expression.